# JodaTime: parsing dates with leading hyphens

Tags: java, jodatime

With JodaTime

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
java.util.Date parsedDate = dtf.parseDateTime("-012-10-25T10:03:22Z").toDate();

System.out.println(parsedDate)
```

prints

```
'Tue Oct 27 04:03:22 CST 13'
```

As you can tell, the local timeZone is CST.

I expect an exception to be thrown as the date that is passed is not in the expected format. or may be a NumberFormatException for, '-' is not a number

Comment: I think it treats `-012` as a number, the `.getYear()` in that date is `-1887`

Comment: Whe you specify a pattern in the `forPattern` method, you must supply a date in that format to `parseDateTime`, and it will give you a valid `Date` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joda supports years before zero (see `DateTimeConstants.BC` that means Before Christ).
So `-012-10-25T10:03:22Z` is treated by Joda like 12 years B.C.

```
DateTime d = dtf.parseDateTime("-012-10-25T10:03:22Z");
System.out.println(d.getEra()); // returns 0 -> that means B.C. era Before Christ
System.out.println(d.getYear()); // returns -12
```

if you want throw exception, then you should do it manualy, becouse Joda doesn't throws exception in this case. Do somethid like

```
   DateTime dateTimeParser(String dateAsString)  
   {  
      DateTime res = dtf.parseDateTime(dateAsString);
      if (d.getYear() < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();  
      return res;  
   }
```

Or use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse `Date`